# Eclipse 3.5 update site returns stale results for / but not for site.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

I'm getting mixed results with an update site I'm setting up:

- Using http://mylyn-mantis.sourceforge.net/eclipse/update/site.xml gets the latest (3.0.2) version
- Using http://mylyn-mantis.sourceforge.net/eclipse/update/ gets me an old ( 3.0.1 ) version

I got some hints about p2 metadata missing - does anyone know what's missing?

---

**Update**: Both artifacts.xml and content.xml have references to the 3.0.2 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw a blog about this at [http://www.jroller.com/andyl/entry/p2\_is\_my\_best\_friend](http://www.jroller.com/andyl/entry/p2%5C_is%5C_my%5C_best%5C_friend)

It seems that it has to do with how the p2 repository is generated for 3.5.

There are some comments on the above blog on how to fix/workaround the issue. I see your on the developer list for mylyn-mantis, so one of the workarounds might help you.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually nailed this down to regenerating the p2 metadata - in multiple steps - but I'm trying to understand before posting an answer.